# Real time system exception handling

Tags: exception, real-time

As always after some research I was unable to find anything of real value.  My question is how does one go about handling exceptions in a real time system?  As program failure generally is not the best case i.e. nuclear reactor/ heart monitor.

Ok since everyone got lost on the second piece of this, which had NOTHING to do with the main question.  I had it in there to show how I normally escape code blocks.

Comment: Regarding the form, the lack of indentation and braces is not good, but I find the early escape approach simpler than opening an extra scope for the else and putting the rest of the function there. The return is pretty clear in a one-liner.

Comment: Fixed the formatting for you. Use four spaces to indent code blocks - backticks are only used for inline stuff.

Comment: Why are you returning a String from a void function?
Why would you pass a null to foo? Or an empty string?
Why are you using strings in a real-time critical program?
Handling exceptions in critical programs is often done well before run time!

Comment: `foo` is declared to return `void` yet you're trying to return a `String`. Thus it won't compile (in any reasonable language). Therefore, it's bad form. Second, I don't know what `foo` is suppose to be doing, but I don't like silent failures. That is, let's say it was the job of `foo` to add `string` to some `set`. With your current code a caller has no idea whether or not the add successfully occurred. This could lead to unpleasant surprises in the future. Third, I hate unbraced conditional code. It's just a maintanence nightmare.

Comment: Dear jeebus.  The main question is about real time exception handling, the second part i added was just how i normally escape code early on.

Comment: I wish someone would tell me why the votes for closing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception handling in real-time/embedded systems has several layers. Not just the language supported options, but also MMU, CPU exceptions and one of my favorites: watchdogs.

Language exceptions (C/C++)
- not often used, beause it is hard to prove that all exceptions are handled at the right level. Also it is pretty hard to determine what threat/process should be responsible. Instead, programming by contract is preferred.

Programming style:
- i.e. programming by contract. Additional constraints : Misra/C Misra/C++. This can be checked to unsure that all possible cases are somehow handled. (i.e. no if without else)

Hardware support:
- MMU : use of multiple processes which are protected against each other. This allows
- watchdog
- CPU exceptions 
- multi core: use of multiple cores to separate cricical processes from the rest. Also allows to have voting mechanisms (you want this and more for your nuclear reactor).
- multi-system

Most important is to define a strategy. Depending on the other nonfunctional requirements (safety, reliability, security) a strategy needs to be thought of. Can be graceful degradation to partial system reboot.

Answer (score 2):

In a 'real-time', 'nuclear reactor' type system, chances are the exception handling allows the system to instead of fail, do the next best thing.

Let's say that we have a heart monitor. If it isn't receiving a signal, that might trigger an exception. In that case, the heart monitor might handle the exception by waiting a few seconds and trying again.

In a nuclear reactor, getting to a certain temperature might trigger an exception. In that case, the handling might shut off various parts of the reactor to start to cool it down, and then start them back up when it gets to a reasonable temperature.

Exceptions are meant to have a lower-level system say that it doesn't know what to do, and to have a higher level system handle it. Like in the nuclear reactor, the system that measures temperature probably doesn't know how to turn on parts of the reactor, so it triggers an exception so that some higher-level system can handle it.

Answer (score -3):

A critical system is like any other system, except it's specified more clearly, passes through more testing phases, and is generally will fail-safe.

Regarding your form, yes it's pretty bad. I do mind the lack of `{}` very much; and it's been said so-often that this is just plain bad style, and leads to confusion when adding new code.

Comment: A critical system has a well-defined politics of error recovery.It  must perform way outside specs while executing a coordinated safety shutdown. While the main loop is pretty straightforward, clean and concise, fault service makes for some very interesting code where you don't take anything for granted, falling back through many levels of failsafes until you reach one that is still reliable and minimizing damage. Also, multiple redundant components watching each other constantly. 90% of resources go towards safety, 10% for actual work.